# How to build out ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

So.. I'm creating an app for a client, the problem is..

I am new to ionic, (I used to create apps using cordova)

I am confused, How do I build out the ionic app?
I am very new to Ionic.

Thanks btw

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/preface.html - Start reading here.

Comment: Do you mean like running the command `ionic build [platform]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to install node.js once you have that installed go to the command line type in:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Or if that does not work do this:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

And then like this

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Once you have that done to start a project you have to do this:
1.) Navigate to where you want your project at.
2.) Type this: `ionic start [appName] blank` And select no for creating a account.
3.) To start the app go to the into your [appName] and type in the command line: `ionic start` and select one of the options and then it will open in the browser.

Use phonegap for getting .apk file, go to build.phonegap.com and zip your ionic project and upload to phonegap and then you will be able to download your .apk file

Comment: i posted a answer please try the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to install the .apk file, I know how to start ionic in a browser 

Comment: well you would use phonegap go to build.phonegap.com and zip your ionic project and upload to phonegap and then you will be able to download your .apk file

Comment: Can I use GitHub url too?